# Cast String to NSObject in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsobject

I have a method that was originally defined to take an `NSString` parameter but now needs to be able to take an `NSString` parameter or an `NSAttributedString` parameter. Unfortunately these do not share an inheritance hierarchy but each inherit from `NSObject`. For this reason, I modified the method to take an `NSObject` and then check the class of the parameter within the method body.

This is working as I would like. However, now I am getting a compiler error from some swift code that calls the method:

`Cannot convert value of String 'String' to expected argument type 'NSObject!'`

I'm only beginning to work with Swift, and this particular code was written by someone else. I tried to surround the string in the method call with `NSObject(...)` but that didn't work. What would be the best way to accommodate this situation?

Comment: Can you add the code about what are you doing?

Comment: Is the method in Swift? If so, you'll want a much better way of expressing "`(NS)String` or `NSAttributedString`" than just an `NSObject` parameter – either an `enum` or a `protocol` depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Cast it with `as`:

Either `str as NSObject` or `str as NSString` will work.

---

**Example:**

```
func test(_ s: NSObject) {
    if s is NSString {
        print("it is an NSString")
    } else if s is NSAttributedString {
        print("it is an NSAttributedString")
    }
}

let str = "hello"
test(str as NSObject)
```

Output:

> it is an NSString

Answer (score 1):

Using the `as` operator should solve your immediate problem.

```
func someFunction(withAnObjectParameter: NSObject!) {
    //...
}

let myString: String = "aString"
let myAttributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()

someFunction(withAnObjectParameter: myString as NSObject)
someFunction(withAnObjectParameter: myAttributedString as NSObject)
```

Here are some links describing its usage in other scenarios:

[swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23)

[developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)